# Getting "No data" response from BOD II in android

Tags: android, obd-ii, elm327

I have developed application to receive OBD II data using ELM 327 (Bluetooth) in android.

Application is working in OBD2 simulator,I10 but it is not working in Suzuki.
Getting response like  below :

Failed to run command. -> Error running 01 46, response: NODATA

May I know , what could be the reason.Application is not working in some cars.

Answer (score 0):

This is completely expected behavior. Besides a few mandatory ones, implementation of almost all OBD2 PIDs is optional. Many vendors do only support a handful of PIDs.

Comment: Hi DrMickey, i am using mcp2515 with nodemcu-32s and am able to receive the messages which have few ids like 2c4, 2c1, 340 etc on the internet i see 2c4 is for rpm and i have verified it too. My question is that no matter which library i use to request the supported pids i send a message like this sendmsgbuf(0x7DF, 0 (ext), 8 (len), then data with 21, 01, 00 etc) and then i get a reply like 7E8,03 ( i assume len), 7F(negative res), 01 (for request), 11 (sub function wrong). I want to know that my car dont support requesting pid’s from it? Or is there something else which i dont know. Thanks

Comment: Try sending the `02 3E 00` to 0x7E0. This is the proper ISOTP request for 'Tester present'. Almost all standard ECUs (if they're not KWP, then try `01 3E`) should answer to that. So you can verify that the communication is working at all.

Comment: ThankYou for replying i got the response from 02 21 00 i didn't know Toyota has 21 mode instead of 21 now i am searching if 21 is for current data or stored data.

Comment: For anyone who come here in future:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76621704/toyota-ecu-replying-0x03-0x7f-0x01-0x11-to-02-01-00-pid-query-request-from-mcp25/76621761#76621761

Comment: i actually made a typo above i was trying with 02 01 00 not with 02 21 00 so after that i tried with 02 21 00 and it worked.